# Have objects with class randomly appear/disappear on loop

Tags: jquery, animation, random

I am trying to emulate a star background.

Stars are created and randomly scattered throughout the site on load. I have got this far adjusting some code.

```
var star="<span class='star'>•</span>";
var numStars=100;
for(var x=1;x<=numStars;x++){
    $(star).appendTo("body");
}
// get window dimentions
var ww = $(window).width();
var wh = $(window).height();
$(".star").each(function(i){
    var posx = Math.round(Math.random() * ww)-20;
    var posy = Math.round(Math.random() * wh)-20;
    $(this).css("top", posy + "px").css("left", posx + "px");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0quLgtaq/3/

I now like to have them each randomly fade in, hold, then fade out.

I'm thinking the approach would be to randomly select a star, then add an .active class to it, then remove it after x seconds. On a loop of sorts.

I'm not totally sure where to start with this. Any rough code to start me off would be great. Thanks

Comment: If I was you I would use HTML5 canvas, maybe something like [particle.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

Comment: @eskimo Looks like a great suggestion, as particle.js has a demo very close to what i am after http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#nasa I will give this ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var star = "<span class='star'>•</span>";
    var numStars = 100;
    for (var x = 1; x <= numStars; x++) {
        var randomDelay = Math.random()*10;
        $(star)
            .css("animation-delay", randomDelay + "s")
            .appendTo("body");
    }
    // get window dimensions
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    $(".star").each(function(i) {
        var posx = Math.round(Math.random() * ww) - 20;
        var posy = Math.round(Math.random() * wh) - 20;
        $(this)
            .css("top", posy + "px")
            .css("left", posx + "px");
    });
});
```

```css
.star {
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade 2s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0quLgtaq/5/).

Comment: Beautiful solution, I've updated slightly to make it loop infinitely. https://jsfiddle.net/0quLgtaq/8/

Comment: Thanks, you can also use some random colors.